# Ошибка в Yii Framework - обязательный author_id

Tags: yii

Делаю простой блог по инструкциии в официальном руководстве фреймворка. Я на этой [странице](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/post.model).

Указываю ваше внимание на данный фрагмент.

Основываясь на анализе требований, изменим метод `rules()` следующим образом:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('title, content, status', 'required'),
        array('title', 'length', 'max'=>128),
        array('status', 'in', 'range'=>array(1,2,3)),
        array('tags', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[\w\s,]+$/',
            'message'=>'В тегах можно использовать только буквы.'),
        array('tags', 'normalizeTags'),

        array('title, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Если я делаю так, как указано в руководстве, сохраняюсь и создаю пост, вылетает ошибка:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`advertable`.`tbl_post`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_post_author` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_user`
>   (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO
>   `tbl_post` (`title`, `content`, `tags`, `status`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1,
>   :yp2, :yp3)

Копаюсь дальше и выясняю, что она возникает только тогда, когда убираю из required author_id. Во-первых, не понял, почему на эту деталь не указали авторы инструкции, во-вторых, поясните мне, пожалуйста - что происходит?

Answer (score 2):

Покопал на форумах и нашел ответ, который решил проблему. Возможно пригодится таким же людям как я:

В случае с внешними ключами нельзя создать пост без автора.
Советую в методе **beforeSave** модели **Post** определять свойство author_id

```
public function beforeSave()
        {
            // Если новая запись - присваиваем id автора
            if($this->isNewRecord)
            {
                if(empty($this->author_id))
                {
                    $this->author_id= Yii::app()->user->id;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Вообще в фреймворке специально определяются отношения между таблицами `relations` чтобы в таблицах можно было не указывать `foreign key` и как раз избежать таких вот ошибок

Comment: В том то и дело что я все указал точь в точь как написано далее в инструкции, но это все равно не помогло и ошибка осталась.

Comment: Там ни единого слова про создание таблиц и том, чтобы вы в `mysql` делали связь между таблицами через `foreign key`. Это вы уже додумали сами....в модели можно написать что это внешний ключ, а вот в самой базе уже не надо делать эти самые ключи

Comment: Таблицы уже созданы авторами инструкции. И даже заполнены. И связи тоже ими прописаны.

Comment: Можно ссылку?.... Как совет: изучайте сразу `yii2`. Он помощнее и много косяков исправлено и более современен, расчитан на новые технологии

Comment: Спасибо. Начал как раз с изучения Yii2 но курс велся на CentOS с применением дополнительного стека технологий вобщем я 3 дня промучался с попыткой настроить виртуальную систему и в конце концов решил отойти назад до изучения Yii1. База данных которую они советуют брать находиться в папке demos идущей с дистрибутивом Yii. Там в папочке data есть готовая база данных этого блока который мы делаем.